# Find rows where a column contains at least one space and no non space characters

Tags: sql-server

the query

```
SELECT *
FROM   table
WHERE  Column_Name = ''
```

list columns  with empty string and column with space character , how can i filter the columns having only space characters in it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So you want all rows where this column contains only one or multiple white-spaces?

```
SELECT * from TableName  
WHERE DATALENGTH(Column_Name) > 0
AND   LEN(Column_Name) = 0
```

`LEN` excludes trailing blanks.

<kbd>[**Sql-Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/a835b/15/0)</kbd>

Comment: The second condition can just be `AND LEN(Column_Name) = 0`. Or `AND Column_Name =''`

Comment: @MartinSmith: Thanks, corrected. I've noticed the difference between `LEN` and `DATALENGTH` but i've forgotten to use it in the second condition.

Answer (score 0):

```
select * from information_schema.columns where rtrim(column_name) = ''
```

Comment: He wants rows where this column contains only one or multiple white-space characters.